# What type should I use for a 2-dimensional array?

Tags: rust

What is wrong with the type of `a` here?

```
fn foo(a: &[&[f64]], x: &[f64]) {
    for i in 0..3 {
        for j in 0..4 {
            println!("{}", a[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let A: [[f64; 4]; 3] = [
        [1.1, -0.2, 0.1, 1.6],
        [0.1, -1.2, -0.2, 2.3],
        [0.2, -0.1, 1.1, 1.5],
    ];
    let mut X: [f64; 3] = [0.0; 3];

    foo(&A, &X);
}
```

I get the compilation failure:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:17:9
   |
17 |     foo(&A, &X);
   |         ^^ expected slice, found array of 3 elements
   |
   = note: expected type `&[&[f64]]`
              found type `&[[f64; 4]; 3]`
```

Comment: How about [this](http://is.gd/rcKOUw)?

Answer (score 17):

*Arrays* are different types from *slices*. Notably, arrays have a fixed size, **known at compile time**. Slices have a fixed size, but **known only at run time**.

I see two straight-forward choices here (see [Levans answer for another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29531983/155423)). The first is to change your function to only accept references to arrays (or the whole array, if you can copy it or don't mind giving up ownership):

```
fn foo(a: &[[f64; 4]; 3], x: &[f64; 3]) {
    for i in 0..3 {
        for j in 0..4 {
            println!("{}", a[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = [
        [1.1, -0.2, 0.1, 1.6],
        [0.1, -1.2, -0.2, 2.3],
        [0.2, -0.1, 1.1, 1.5],
    ];

    let x = [0.0; 3];

    foo(&a, &x);
}
```

The other easy change is to make your declaration into references:

```
fn foo(a: &[&[f64]], x: &[f64]) {
    for i in 0..3 {
        for j in 0..4 {
            println!("{}", a[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = [
        &[1.1, -0.2, 0.1, 1.6][..],
        &[0.1, -1.2, -0.2, 2.3][..],
        &[0.2, -0.1, 1.1, 1.5][..],
    ];

    let x = [0.0; 3];

    foo(&a, &x);
}
```

Note that this second example, we can use the implicit coercion of a reference to an array to a slice, when we just pass in `&a` and `&x`. However, we *cannot* rely on that for the nested data in `a`. `a` has already been defined to be an array of arrays, and we can't change the element type.

Also a **word of caution** - you really should use the length method of the slice in your ranges, otherwise you can easily `panic!` if you walk off the end.

```
fn foo(a: &[&[f64]], x: &[f64]) {
    for i in 0..a.len() {
        let z = &a[i];
        for j in 0..z.len() {
            println!("{}", z[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Other stylistic changes I made to meet the Rust style:

1. variables are `snake_case`
2. space after `:`
3. space after `;`
4. space around `=`
5. space after `,`

Answer (score 9):

As an alternative to Shepmaster's good explanation on the mechanisms, there is actually another way to have your function accept any mix of **arrays** and **slices** (and even `Vec`): it involves using generics with the [`AsRef`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html) trait.

the idea is to write your function like this:

```
use std::convert::AsRef;

fn foo<S, T, U>(a: S, x: U)
where
    T: AsRef<[f64]>,
    S: AsRef<[T]>,
    U: AsRef<[f64]>,
{
    let slice_a = a.as_ref();
    for i in 0..slice_a.len() {
        let slice_aa = slice_a[i].as_ref();
        for j in 0..slice_aa.len() {
            println!("{}", slice_aa[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

This is quite a function, but is in fact quite simple: `S` must coerce to a `&[T]` via the `AsRef` trait, and `T` must coerce to `&[f64]` similarly. On the same way `U` must coerce to `&[f64]`, but we do not necessarily have `U == T` !

This way, `S` can be an array of slices, an array of array, a `Vec` of arrays or of slices, an array of Vec... Any combination is possible as long as the types implement the `AsRef` trait.

Be careful though: the `AsRef` trait is only implemented for arrays up to the size 32.