# How do I pass a Vec<Vec<i32>> to a function?

Tags: vector, rust

Given a 2D vector of `i32`s:

```
let v = vec![
    vec![1, 1, 1], 
    vec![0, 1, 0], 
    vec![0, 1, 0],
];
```

How can I pass it to a function to ultimately print its details? I tried:

```
fn printVector(vector: &[[i32]]) {
    println!("Length{}", vector.len())
}
```

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102786/two-dimensional-vectors-in-rust

Comment: Idiomatic Rust uses `snake_case` for variables, methods, macros, and fields; `UpperCamelCase` for types; and `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` for statics and constants. Use `print_vector` instead, please.

Comment: See also [What type should I use for a 2-dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29523895/155423); [Creating a Vector of Vectors in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35630131/155423); [How can you easily borrow a Vec<Vec<T>> as a &[&[T\]\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50056778/155423).

Comment: How do you want to pass `v` to the function? As value? As [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.reference.html)? Do you need the function to handle `Vec` or is a [slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/) enough? See *[What is the difference between passing a value to a function by reference and passing it by Box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27305585)*

Comment: It has nothing to do with offending eyes or something. This is the warning from the rust compiler: *warning: function `printVector` should have a snake case name such as `print_vector`*

Comment: I'm aware of the compiler warnings. It's just a silly thing to complain about. Lots of helpful people gave me actual solutions rather than nit pick the question syntax. Those are the people who actually make stackover flow worth using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you easily borrow a Vec<Vec<T>> as a &\[&\[T\]\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50056778/how-can-you-easily-borrow-a-vecvect-as-a-t)

Comment: @camccar After his comment on the syntax, Shepmaster did your job and researched similar questions, and then gave you links to 3 different relevant questions. Those are the people who actually make stackoverflow worth using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fn printVector(vector: &Vec<Vec<i32>>) {
    println!("Length{}", vector.len())
}

let v = vec![
    vec![1, 1, 1],
    vec![0, 1, 0],
    vec![0, 1, 0],
];
printVector(&v);
```

In this example, `&Vec<Vec<i32>` and `&[Vec<i32>]` are no different; maybe you want to change to this:

```
fn print_vector(vector: &[Vec<i32>]) {
    for i in vector {
        for j in i {
            println!("{}", j)
        }
    }
}

let v = vec![
    vec![1, 1, 1],
    vec![0, 1, 0],
    vec![0, 1, 0],
];
print_vector(&v);
```

Answer (score 8):

You may use a function which accepts a slice of `T` where `T` can also be referenced as a slice:

```
fn print_vector<T>(value: &[T])
where
    T: AsRef<[i32]>,
{
    for slice in value {
        println!("{:?}", slice.as_ref())
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ecbcdcb5354e7e4c9b3360f555caf40b&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

If you want to accept any type instead of just `i32`, you can also generalize this:

```
fn print_vector<T, D>(value: &[T])
where
    T: AsRef<[D]>,
    D: Debug,
{
    for slice in value {
        println!("{:?}", slice.as_ref())
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3957f5b3647c33de9c65d850d98093b9&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Answer (score 5):

Since you're going to pass vectors to your function, the following code should work:

```
fn print_vector(vector: Vec<Vec<i32>>) {
    println!("Length{}", vector.len())
}
```

Comment:  This is the only answer which accepts a `Vec` as an argument, not a reference to one.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass a slice of vectors - `&[Vec<i32>]`, not a slice of slices:

```
fn print_vector(vector: &[Vec<i32>]) {
    println!("Length {}", vector.len())
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![vec![1, 1, 1], vec![0, 1, 0], vec![0, 1, 0]];
    print_vector(&v);
}
```

[Playground](http://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b5ebdc1768148ceb14d40eac79efa3eb&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)